# Fastest unconditional sort algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a function, which can take two elements and return them back in ascending order:

```
void Sort2(int &a, int &b) { 
  if (a < b) return; 
  int t = a; 
  a = b; 
  b = t; 
}
```

**what is the fastest way to sort an array with N entries using this function if I am not allowed to use extra conditional operators?**
That means that whole my program should look like this:

```
int main(){
  int a[N];
     // fill a array

  const int NS = ...; // number of comparison, depending on N.
  const int c[NS] = { {0,1}, {0,2}, ... }; // consequence of indices pairs generated depending on N.
  for( int i = 0; i < NS; i++ ) {
    Sort2(a[c[i][0]], a[c[i][1]]);
  }
     // sort is finished
  return 1;
}
```

Most of the fast sort algorithms use conditions to decide what to do. There is [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) of course, but it takes M = N(N-1)/2 comparisons. This is not the optimum, for instance, with N = 4 it takes M = 6 comparison, meanwhile 4 entries can be sorted with 5:

```
Sort2(a[0],a[1]);
Sort2(a[2],a[3]);
Sort2(a[1],a[3]);
Sort2(a[0],a[2]);
Sort2(a[1],a[2]);
```

---

Comment: May be you are looking for a non-comparative sort. Go for [Radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).

Comment: @sgar91 That doesn't help. How do you sort with radix sort using only the provided sort function?

Comment: What do you mean by not using comparison operators? Any loop you use shall have comparison operators for termination condition. Do you mean comparison between elements are not allowed?

Comment: Abhishek, you can reformulate this that way. Also you can say that N is known and loops are forbidden as well (like in the example with N=5).

Comment: What purpose does these limitations serve?

Comment: Read about sorting networks. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network

Comment: that `if` in Sort2() looks pretty conditional to me ;-)

Comment: @zch What is a "comparator" if not a conditional operator?

Comment: I have added an example code draft.

Comment: @RossPatterson - in sorting networks it's 2 element sorter - op has shown implementation that he is allowed to use.

Comment: zch, I believe the sorting network is what I need, why don't you make the answer from your comment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard approach is known as [Bitonic Mergesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_sorter). It is hella efficient when paralellized, and only slightly less efficient than conventional algorithms when not parallelized. Bitonic mergesort is a special kind of a wider class of algorithms known as "sorting networks"; it is unusual among sorting networks in that some of its reorderings are in *reverse* order of the desired sort (though everything is in the correct order once the algorithm completes). You can do that with your `Sort2` by passing in a higher array slot for the first argument than the second.

Answer (score 0):

For `N` a power of 2 you can generalize the approach you used, by using a "merge-sortish"  kind of approach: you sort the first half and the last half separately, and then merge these using a few comparisons.

For instance, consider an array of size 8. And assume that the first half is sorted and the last half is sorted (by applying this same approach recursively):

```
A B C D P Q R S
```

In the first round, you do a comparison of 1 vs 1, 2 vs 2, etc:

```
---------
|       |
| ---------
| |     | |
A B C D P Q R S
    | |     | |
    | ---------
    |       |
    ---------
```

After this round, the first and the last element are in the right place, so you need to repeat the process for the inner 6 elements (I keep the names of the elements the same, because it is unknown where they end up):

```
  -------
  |     |
  | -------
  | |   | |
A B C D P Q R S
      |     |
      -------
```

In the next round, the inner 4 elements are compared, and in the last round the inner 2.

Let `f(n)` be the number of comparisons needed to sort an array of length `n` (where `n` is a power of 2, for the moment). Clearly, an array consisting of 1 element is sorted already:

```
f(1) = 0
```

For a longer array, you first need to sort both halves, and then perform the procedure described above. For `n=8`, that took `4+3+2+1 = (n/2)(n/2+1)/2` comparisons. Hence in general:

```
f(n) = 2 f(n/2) + (n/2)(n/2+1)/2
```

Note that for `n=4`, this indeed gives:

```
f(4) = 2 f(2) + 2*3/2
     = 2 * (2 f(1) + 1*2/2) + 3
     = 5
```

---

To facilitate `n`s that are no power of 2, the important thing is to do the merging step on an odd-length array. The simplest strategy seems to be to compare the smallest element of both subarrays (which yields the smallest element) and then just continue on the rest of the array (which has now even length).

If we write `g(k) = k(k+1)/2`, we can now have a short way of writing the recursive formula (I use `2k` and `2k+1` to distinguish even and odd):

```
f(1) = 0
f(2k) = 2 f(k) + g(k)
f(2k+1) = f(k+1) + f(k) + 1 + g(k)
```

---

Some pseudocode on how to approach this:

```
function sort(A, start, length) {
    if (length == 1) {
        // do nothing
    } else if (length is even) {
        sort(A, start, length/2)
        sort(A, start+length/2, length/2)
        merge(A, start, length)
    } else if (length is odd) {
        sort(A, start, length/2+1)
        sort(A, start+length/2+1, length/2)
        Sort2(A[start], A[start+length/2+1])
        merge(A, start+1, length-1)            
    }
}

function merge(A, start, length) {
    if (length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < length/2; i++)
            Sort2(A[i], A[i]+length/2)
        merge(A, start+1, length-2)
    }
}
```

And you would run this on your array by

```
sort(A, 0, A.length)
```

Comment: This algorithm is O(n^2). It'll work, but there are simpler and faster approaches available. Sorting networks are not good at monotonic merges, since their associations between slots are predefined.